# Clarify the difference between "program" and "programme"

Tags: nouns, writing

What is the difference between The Noun: Program and Programme ??

What should i use?

Comment: A "programme" is a "program" with it's pinky raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From daily writing tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/get-with-the-programme/)

American English always uses *program*.

British English used *program* until 19th cent., when, under French influence, it became *programme* (unless referring to computers.)

Australian English recommends *program* for official usage, but *programme* is still in common use.

Comment: In Australia, programme is making ['an official' comeback](http://www.smh.com.au/national/public-service/get-with-the-programme-public-servants-20131002-2us38.html).